# c++ convert time_t to string and back again

Tags: c++, time

I want to convert a time_t to a string and back again.

I'd like to convert the time to a string using ctime().

I can't seem to find anything on google or the time.h header file, any ideas?

Basically what I'm trying to do is store a date in a file, and then read it back so I can use it as a time_t again.

**Also, no library references outside of std,mfc.**

One more note, this will have to function on Windows xp and above and that's it.

## Edit

All I want to do is convert a time_t into a string(I don't care if it's human readable) and then convert it back to a time_t. I'm basically just trying to store the time_t into a file and read it again(but I don't want any code for that, as there will be more info in the file besides a time_t).

Comment: Do you want a human readable string, like "2011-08-18 21:07:10"?

Comment: I'm surprised none has anything over a 0 on here, they were all good answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll have to write your own function to do that. These functions convert any primitive type (or any type which overloads operator<< and/or operator>>) to a string, and viceversa:

```
template<typename T>
std::string StringUtils::toString(const T &t) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << t;
    return oss.str();
}

template<typename T>
T StringUtils::fromString( const std::string& s ) {
    std::istringstream stream( s );
    T t;
    stream >> t;
    return t;
}
```

Comment: My initial answer was just the first sentence, I think the downvotes are previous to the edit in which I added the code

Comment: Ah ok. Will this cover the Edit I posted above?

Comment: @kelton52: Yes. You can use .c_str() with the generated string if you need to write to a binary file

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, it worked great. I had to do a little converting from wchar_t 's to char's, but that's what I get for working on someone elses project :p. Anyways, it was simple and worked great.

Answer (score 3):

The [time_t Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_t) article sheds some light on this. The bottom line is that the type of `time_t` is not guaranteed in the C specification. Here is an example of what you can try:

Try `stringstream`.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

time_t seconds;
time(&seconds);

std::stringstream ss;
ss << seconds;
std::string ts = ss.str();
```

A nice wrapper around the above technique is Boost's lexical_cast:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>

time_t t;
time(&t);

std::string ts = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(seconds);
```

Wikipedia on time_t:

> The `time_t` datatype is a data type in
>   the ISO C library defined for storing
>   system time values. Such values are
>   returned from the standard `time()`
>   library function. This type is a
>   typedef defined in the standard
>    header. **ISO C defines
>   time_t as an arithmetic type, but does
>   not specify any particular type**,
>   range, resolution, or encoding for it.
>   Also unspecified are the meanings of
>   arithmetic operations applied to time
>   values.
>
> **Unix and POSIX-compliant systems implement the `time_t` type as a `signed
>   integer` (typically 32 or 64 bits wide)
>   which represents the number of seconds
>   since the start of the Unix epoch**:
>   midnight UTC of January 1, 1970 (not
>   counting leap seconds). Some systems
>   correctly handle negative time values,
>   while others do not. Systems using a
>   32-bit `time_t` type are susceptible to
>   the [Year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Comment: Please read my post. The problem isn't converting it to a string, it's converting it back, that's where I can't find any information.

Comment: @kelton: Int to String is pretty straightforward. You are going to have to expand about your requirements.

Comment: Ok, all I really need to do is convert a time_t into any kind of string, and then back again. I don't really care if it's human readable, I just want to store it in a file.

Comment: @kelton: Then use `atoi()` to convert back on `std::string time.c_str()`.

Answer (score 3):

`ctime()` returns a pointer to a character buffer that uses a specific formatting.  You could use `sprintf()` to parse such a string into its individual portions, store them in a `struct tm`, and use `mktime()` to convert that to a `time_t`.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the time_t to struct tm using [gmtime()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gmtime.html), then convert the struct tm to plain text (preferably ISO 8601 format) using [strftime()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html). The result will be portable, human readable, and machine readable.

To get back to the time_t, you just parse the string back into a struct tm and use [mktime()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mktime.html).

Answer (score 1):

The other answer with `stringstream` will give you an integer non-readable (as requested in the question).

If you prefer a readable answer, here it is :

```
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
time_t timeAsTimeT = /** init your time here **/ ;
std::string myStr = std::asctime(std::localtime(&timeAsTimeT);
```