# C++ convert string to time_t

Tags: c++, c, time, stat

I'm using `stat.st_mtime` to get my last modification time of a directory and then store it into a `file.txt` (stored string is something like that : `1467035651`)

Later when I retrieved data from  my `file.txt`, I tried to convert my string from my *file.txt* to `int` type  since the string contains just seconds but I don't know if it's a good idea to do that.

Is there any way to convert directly to `time_t`?

Comment: Just read it to a time_t.

Comment: Pick a language please!

Comment: For C++ a duplicate to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7113396/694576

Comment: @alk Proposed duplicate restricts to "this will have to function on Windows xp" - certainly a _near_ duplicate.  (it really is a compiler issue, not an OS one) This likely prevents using `_Generic` for type discrimination as being acceptable to that OP.

Comment: @kfsone: better don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t) `time_t` is just an unspecified numeric format.

Just directly read back the numeric value from the file, there's no need for special conversions:

```
time_t t;
std::ifstream input("File.txt");
// ...
input >> t;
```

Comment: Nice C++ answer.  C is challenging as `time_t` maybe an integer or FP.

Answer (score 4):

The function `atoll` in `stdlib.h` should work. Example:

```
time_t t;
char *time_string = //...

t = (time_t) atoll(time_string);
```

Comment: On exceptional platforms `time_t` is floating point.  `atoll(time_string)` may truncate significant fractional digits.

Comment: @chux: It could even be a `struct` :-O

Comment: The `ato*()` functions are error prone as they ***do not*** provide a safe way to detect errors during conversion.

Comment: @alk `time_t` must be a _real type_ (integers FP) - this does not allow `struct`.

Comment: Since the structure `stat` is defined in C POSIX library header `sys/stat.h`, I think it's enough to convert `stat.st_mtime` string to `time_t` value. Although `time_t` is not defined by the C standard, it's almost always an integral value. Maybe my solution is quite a proper way to solve this problem.

Comment: Had the post been tagged `POSIX`, I would agree with you.  `stat.st_mtime` is not only used by `POSIX`.

Answer (score 2):

[Assuming C]

The `strto*()` family of functions provides fail safe ways to convert a C-"string" to an integer, [`signed`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtoll.3p.html) or [`unsigned`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtoul.3.html), as well as to [`float` and `double`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtod.3p.html).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to convert directly to time_t?

Various other answers have posted direct solutions with strengths and weaknesses.

> contains just seconds but I don't know if it's a good idea to do that.

Answer depends on the goal.  IMO, it is the wrong approach

Rather than save/reading as some compiler dependent format, consider using [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standards and save the time-stamp in a textual standard version that clearly denotes the time zone, preferable universal time.

Example C code as post is tagged `C`.
For *writing*, something like

```
// Minimum size to store a ISO 8601 date/time stamp
//YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss\0
#define N (4 + 5*3 + 1 + 1)

time_t x;
struct tm *tm = gmtime(&x);
if (tm == NULL) {
  return failure;
}

char dest[N + 1];
int cnt = snprintf(dest, sizeof(dest), "%04d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02dZ", 
    tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon+1, tm.tm_mday,
    tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
if (cnt < 0 || cnt >= sizeof(dest)) {
  return failure;
}
```

Additional code need for fractional seconds.
Also see `ftime( ,  , "%FT%T %z", )`.

What would you rather read in `file.txt`?

```
1467035651
```

or

```
2016-06-27T13:54:11Z
```